# Hartogs space of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose :

$U=\chi(\mathbb{N})$ is the Hartogs space of $\mathbb{N}$.

$(M_a)_{a\in U}$ a family of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $a<b \rightarrow  M_b\subseteq M_a$.

I'm trying (without any luck) to prove that there exists $a_0\in U$ such that for all $a\geq a_0 \rightarrow M_a=M_{a_0}$.

Hartogs space of a set A is:

A well ordered space $\chi(A)$ such that :

- $\chi(A)\nleq_c A$
- $\chi(A)$ is the least set with that property (if $W$ is a well ordered set such that $W\nleq_c A$ then $\chi(A)\leq_0 W$).

$A\leq_c B$ if the cardinality of the set B is greater than or equal to the cardinality of A.

$\chi(A)\leq_0 W$ if $X(A)$ is an initial segment of $W$ that is there exists $w\in W$ such that $X(A)=_0 \{y\in W|y<w\}$

**Thank you in advance for your time and effort.**

Comment: What do you mean by "Hartogs space"?

Comment: I'm using the definition provided here: http://f3.tiera.ru/2/M_Mathematics/MA_Algebra/MAa_Abstract%20algebra/Moschovakis%20Y.%20Notes%20on%20set%20theory%20(2ed.,%20Springer,%202006)(ISBN%200387287221)(O)(291s)_MAa_.pdf pg100 theorem 7.34

Comment: First of all, if you are trying to follow a particular proof it is best to cite that source. Not everyone uses the same notation, terminology and definitions. Secondly, I'm not clear on your question here. Did you construct $\chi(\Bbb N)$ and you are trying to prove something about it, or what?

Comment: It's an exercise I'm trying to solve. I've constructed $\chi(\mathbb{N})$ and I'm trying to prove that if such a family $(M_a)_{a\in \chi({\mathbb{N}})}$ exists then after some $a_0\in\chi(\mathbb{N})$ it must become "constant"

Comment: what does $\le_c$ mean? What does $\le_0$ mean?

Comment: $A\leq_c B$ means that the cardinality of B is greater than or equal to the cardinality of A.

Comment: What you want to prove is false (think of Dedekind cuts). But really, add the relevant definitions to the post, not in the comments.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I'm not sure this is false. This is an exam exercise and it is very unlikely.

Comment: @epsilon Yes, I noticed I was reading incorrectly some of your conditions. There cannot be such chains, because otherwise, for each $a$, if $a'$ is the successor of $a$, you can pick the least number in $M_a\setminus M_{a'}$, and this gives you an uncountable set of numbers.

Comment: Have you tried to understand my hint? Or Andres' last comment?

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes but I'm still working on a few things. Following your hint I did the following (I'm not really sure though about my solution): Since $\chi(\mathbb{N})$ is well ordered it has a least element let's call it $0$ and then $M_0$ is also the first set in the sequence defined above. Assuming the set sequence doesn't become 'constant' I can find $b,c\in \chi(\mathbb{N})$ with $b<c$ such that $M_c\subset M_b$. I can pick $x_0\in\M_0$ such that $x_0\in M_b\setminus M_c$. I then move to the next set etc.Picking different elements from each set I have a contradiction $M_0>_c \mathbb{N}$

Comment: You got the gist, but your argument is badly written.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thank you for helping out, I'll work a bit more on the details.

Comment: What does $\le_0$ mean?

Comment: @CameronBuie $A\leq_0 B$  means there exists a monomorphism $\pi$ from  $A$ to $B$ which respects the ordering $(x\leq_{A} y\iff \pi(x)\leq_{B} \pi(y))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Recall that the Hartogs of $\Bbb N$ is a well-ordered set, therefore so is the chain $(\{M_a\mid a\in U\},\subseteq)$. Find a way of picking out a unique element from each $M_a$, i.e. $a\neq b$ implies that the choice is distinct between $a$ and $b$.