# Is my claim wrong?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question is strongly related to this one.

[Hartogs space of $\mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615850/hartogs-space-of-mathbbn?noredirect=1#comment1298458_615850)

My claim is the following:

1. $\chi(\mathbb{N})$ is well ordered and infinite.
2. There exists $\pi: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \chi(\mathbb{N})$ one to one.
3. $\pi[\mathbb{N}]=\{a_1,a_2,...\}$ with $a_i\in\chi(\mathbb{N})$ for $i=1,2,...$ and suppose $a_i<a_j$ for $i<j$.
4. $M_{a_i}=\{i,i+1,...\}\subset \mathbb{N}$ and $M_{a_i}\supset M_{a_j}$ for $j>i$.
5. If $0$ is the least element of $\chi(\mathbb{N})$ I’m constructing a sequence of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ as follows:

$M_0=...=M_{a_1}\supset M_{s(a_1)}=...=M_{a_2}\supset M_{s(a_2)}=...$

Since there has to be a $a_0\in \chi(\mathbb{N})$ (the conclusion of the related question) such that for all $a>a_0$ , $M_a=M_{a_0}$ I’m either wrong (please point out where) or for every possible one to one function $\pi$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\chi(\mathbb{N})$ there exists a $a_0\in \chi(\mathbb{N})$ such that for every $b\in\pi[\mathbb{N}]$, $b<a_0$ (if so how can I prove this?)
Feel free to point out any other suggestion or something I’m not taking into account.

$s(a)$ is the successor of $a$

$\chi(\mathbb{N})$ is the Hartogs set of $\mathbb{N}$. The Hartogs  set $\chi(A)$ of a set $A$ is well ordered set such that there exists no injection from $\chi(A)$ to $A$ and also $\chi(A)$ is the minimal set with this property.

for more details on Hartogs' set pg100 theorem 7.34 of the following

[http://f3.tiera.ru/2/M_Mathematics/MA_Algebra/MAa_Abstract%20algebra/Moschovakis%20Y.%20Notes%20on%20set%20theory%20(2ed.,%20Springer,%202006)(ISBN%200387287221)(O)(291s)*MAa*.pdf](http://f3.tiera.ru/2/M_Mathematics/MA_Algebra/MAa_Abstract%20algebra/Moschovakis%20Y.%20Notes%20on%20set%20theory%20%282ed.,%20Springer,%202006%29%28ISBN%200387287221%29%28O%29%28291s%29_MAa_.pdf)

**Thank you in advance for your time and effort.**

Comment: In the earlier question you linked to, there was a set $M_a$ for each $a\in\chi(\mathbb N)$. In the present question, You have, in item 4, introduced $M_a$ only when $a$ is one of the countably many elements $a_i\in\pi[\mathbb N]$; in item 5, you apparently extend this to $a$'s that are between two such $a_i$'s or before $a_1$. But you still don't have any $M_a$ for most $a\in\chi(\mathbb N)$. So I don't see how you can import the result from the earlier question into the present context.

Comment: @AndreasBlass After a long night I think I managed to prove the following (which actually proves the claim about the existance of a monomorphism): If $U,V$ are well ordered sets and $\pi:U\rightarrow V$ a monomorphism which respects the ordering ($x\leq_U y\iff \pi(x)\leq_V \pi(y)$) then $p[U]=seg_V(w)=\{y\in V| y<w\}$. So yes you're right there is a $a_0\in\chi(\mathbb{N})$ such that for all $a>a_0$ I don't have $M_a$ for most $a\in\chi(\mathbb{N})$. Andreas thank you for your time. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: The result you say you proved seems to be missing a hypothesis. Suppose, for example, that both $U$ and $V$ are the set of natural numbers, with the usual ordering, and that $\pi$ is defined by $\pi(n)=2n$. What is true, though, is that if $U$ is an infinite well-ordered set and $V$ is its Hartogs ordinal, then any function from $U$ into $V$ has its range included in $\text{seg}_V(w)$ for some $w\in V$.  This seems to be what's relevant to your question and my previous comment.

Comment: @AndreasBlass you're right of course... I really liked my proof lol     I'll try and prove your claim  (more homework lol) Don't be too surprised if you see me posting again in few days:) . You've been most helpfull, thank you again.